# Consider the following snippet. Which component will be rendered based on the conditions applied?

Tags: reactjs

Consider the following snippet. Which component will be rendered based on the conditions applied?

[image]

What will be the output i am getting error

Comment: Homework? React will render. This is terrible code. Don't learn from it.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is React js

1st condition course array length is not  less than zero hence false condition
it will go to this.state.Html[0] and that is also false hence answer will be React js